# What's wrong with my syntax? -Ext JS

Tags: class, extjs, syntax, toolbar

I'm having a syntax issue here in my Ext application. I assume it's syntax because it works fine in Firefox but not Internet Explorer

```
layout: 'vbox',
tbar: Ext.create('AM.view.TopToolbar', {}), //Trouble Code
items: [ ...
```

Any ideas?

Error in IE:

```
SCRIPT16389: Unspecified error. 
ext-all-debug.js, line 5017 character 17
```

app/view/TopToolbar.js:

```
Ext.define('AM.view.TopToolbar', {
    extend: 'Ext.Toolbar',
    alias: 'widget.toptoolbar',
    defaults: { arrowCls: '' }, //Removing black arrow from toolbar items
    items: [
        { text : 'Tools' }
    ] 
}); // this is the entire toolbar so far
```

Comment: What kind of wrong is this? How do you know it's here? I guess the error is bellow what you've paste... Can we see more?

Comment: Edited to include error

Comment: I bet you've got a trailing comma in your items array, or something in your config. That's typically the kind or things FF and Chrome let pass, but not IE.

Comment: Not sure if it is just a copy/paste error, but `vbar` is not a valid layout...

Comment: it's vbox in my code, my mistake. not the reason though

Comment: Please provide Extjs version, example 4.2.1.

Comment: 4.1.1. There are no trailing commas, it's the single line that Creates an instance of my TopToolbar class

Comment: Oh yes, you're right, the error message clearly states that it crashes later on in Ext code. Assuming IE idiosyncrasies are taken into account by Ext, that means that your error is in the code of your AM.view.TopToolbar class or one of its ramifications.

Comment: Can you post the code for 'TopToolbar' its likely the issue is there

Comment: It's certainly that you use a variable before declare it. Works fine in firecofx & chrome but IE needs all the variable. Create a Var.js file when you put all your variables inside. Then if the error is still there, use a Syntax Corrector like JSLint